# PostgreSQL: Create table if not exists AS

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I'm using PostgreSQL and am an SQL beginner. I'm trying to create a table from a query, and if I run:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name AS
   (....query...)
```

it works just fine. But then if I add 'if not exists' and run:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name AS
   (....query...)
```

using exactly the same query, I get:

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"
> ```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[CREATE TABLE AS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html) is considered a separate statement from a normal [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html), and *until Postgres version 9.5* (see [changelog entry](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5.html#AEN127121)) didn't support an `IF NOT EXISTS` clause. (Be sure to look at the correct version of the manual for the version you are using.)

Although not quite as flexible, the `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` syntax might be an alternative in some situations; rather than taking its structure (and content) from a `SELECT` statement, it copies the structure of another table or view.

Consequently, you could write something like this (untested); the final insert is a rather messy way of doing nothing if the table is already populated:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW source_data AS SELECT * FROM foo NATURAL JOIN bar;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS snapshot LIKE source_data;

INSERT INTO snapshot
SELECT * FROM source_data
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM snapshot );
```

Alternatively, if you want to discard previous data (e.g. an abandoned temporary table), you could conditionally drop the old table, and unconditionally create the new one:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_stuff;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_stuff AS SELECT * FROM foo NATURAL JOIN bar;
```

Comment: I'll play around with your suggestion. Thanks - I appreciate it.

Comment: If you are going to create a `VIEW` in order to copy the table structure, you might go all the way and use a **[`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)** instead.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hm, that's true. Except that that doesn't accept an `IF NOT EXISTS` clause either; you can `DROP MATERIALISED VIEW IF EXISTS`, though. Without knowing the exact use case, it's hard to know if any of these options are actually relevant.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter be specific in the `PostgreSQL version` that supports _feature_ because  `MATERIALIZED VIEW` supports `PostgreSQL version 9.3` and above

Comment: @WingedPanther: Correct. I tend to assume the current version of Postgres for questions that can't be bothered to declare the actual version in use.

Comment: Is it that `IF NOT EXISTS` isn't allowed on `CREATE TABLE AS`, or does something in the query conflict with using `IF NOT EXISTS`? The reason I ask is - you (very helpfully) distinguish and link to documentation for `CREATE TABLE` vs `CREATE TABLE AS`, but the `CREATE TABLE AS` page includes `IF NOT EXISTS` in its synopsis, so it's not clear what exactly causes the issue.

Comment: @dwanderson At the time of writing, `CREATE TABLE AS` *didn't* support the option; apparently it [was added in version 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5.html#AEN127121). I guess I should update the answer for those lucky enough to be running a nice up to date version. :)

Comment: Ahh, that explains it all - we're on 9.4, so we just missed it (which is why I ended up on this page in the first place - `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... AS` didn't work for me). Thanks for looking into it, and for the prompt reply to a question over 2 years old!

Comment: In version 9.3 at least, the `LIKE source_data` piece needs to be enclosed in parentheses, otherwise the line won't execute

Answer (score 7):

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` was added in Postgres 9.1. See:

- [PostgreSQL create table if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766046/postgresql-create-table-if-not-exists/7438222#7438222)

#### Postgres 9.0 or older

If you are going to write a function for this, base it on [system catalog table **`pg_class`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html), not on views in the [information schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) or the [statistics collector](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html) (which only exist if activated).

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table_qry(_tbl text
                                          , _qry text
                                          , _schema text = NULL)
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sch text := COALESCE(_schema, current_schema());
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
      JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      WHERE  n.nspname = _sch
      AND    c.relname = _tbl
      ) THEN
   
      RAISE NOTICE 'Name is not free: %.%',_sch, _tbl;
      RETURN  FALSE;
   ELSE
      EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I.%I AS %s', _sch, _tbl, _qry);

      RAISE NOTICE 'Table created successfully: %.%',_sch, _tbl;
      RETURN  TRUE;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

The function takes a table name and the query string, and optionally also a schema to create the table in (defaults to the [current schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)).

Note the correct use of `=` in the function header and `:=` in the function body:

- [The forgotten assignment operator "=" and the commonplace ":="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace/22001209#22001209)

Also note how identifiers are escaped as identifiers. You can't use `regclass`, since the table does not exist, yet:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Answer (score 1):

CTAS (Create Table AS) for **REDSHIFT** PLPGSQL flavor. Shout out to [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) for the root idea using pure PG syntax.

```
CREATE
OR
REPLACE
PROCEDURE pipeline.sp_create_table_if_not_exists_as (sch VARCHAR, tbl VARCHAR, qry VARCHAR, tbl_attrs VARCHAR)
 AS
    /*
     specifically an exception for CTAS functionality: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html
    */
$$
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
   JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
   WHERE  n.nspname = sch
   AND    c.relname = tbl
   ) THEN

   RAISE INFO 'Table already exists: %.%', sch, tbl;
ELSE
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || sch || '.' || tbl || ' ' || tbl_attrs || ' AS ' || qry;
    RAISE INFO 'Table created successfully: %.%, using query: [%], optional attributes: [%]', sch, tbl, qry, tbl_attrs;
END IF;

END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create or replace function create_table(tblname text) returns text as
$$ 
BEGIN
$1 = trim($1);
IF not EXISTS (select relname from pg_stat_user_tables where relname =$1) THEN
execute 'create table '||$1||' as select * from tbl'; -- <put your query here>
return ''||$1||' Created Successfully !!';
else
return  ''||$1||' Already Exists !!';
END IF;
END
$$
language plpgsql
```

---

```
create or replace function create_table_qry(tblname text,qry text) returns text as
$$ 
BEGIN
$1 = trim($1);
IF not EXISTS (select relname from pg_stat_user_tables where relname =$1) THEN
execute 'create table '||$1||' as '||$2||'';
return ''||$1||' Created Successfully !!';
else
return  ''||$1||' Already Exists !!';
END IF;
END
$$
language plpgsql
```

Comment: There are a couple of weak spots in the function. To much for a comment, I added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

It’s simple:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc ( sql_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
   AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, sender VARCHAR(20) NULL)
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: The poster asked about `create table as` not `create table`.  For `create table`, yes, `if not exists` is supported

Answer (score 0):

Use do :

```
do $$ begin

if not exists (  SELECT 1
   FROM   information_schema.tables 
   WHERE  table_schema = 'schema_name'
   AND    table_name = 'bla ') then

  create table schema_name.bla as select * from blu;
end if;

end $$;
```