# In Redshift, how do you combine CTAS with the "if not exists" clause?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm having some trouble getting this table creation query to work, and I'm wondering if I'm running in to a limitation in redshift.

Here's what I want to do:
I have data that I need to move between schema, and I need to create the destination tables for the data on the fly, but only if they don't already exist.

Here are queries that I know work:

```
create table if not exists temp_table (id bigint);
```

This creates a table if it doesn't already exist, and it works just fine.

```
create table temp_2 as select * from temp_table where 1=2;
```

So that creates an empty table with the same structure as the previous one.  That also works fine.

However, when I do this query:

```
create table if not exists temp_2 as select * from temp_table where 1=2;
```

Redshift chokes and says there is an error near as (for the record, I did try removing "as" and then it says there is an error near select)

I couldn't find anything in the redshift docs, and at this point I'm just guessing as to how to fix this.  Is this something I just can't do in redshift?

I should mention that I absolutely can separate out the queries that selectively create the table and populate it with data, and I probably will end up doing that. I was mostly just curious if anyone could tell me what's wrong with that query.

EDIT:

I do not believe this is a duplicate.  The post linked to offers a number of solutions that rely on user defined functions...redshift doesn't support UDF's.  They did recently implement a python based UDF system, but my understanding is that its in beta, and we don't know how to implement it anyway.

Thanks for looking, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL create table if not exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766046/postgresql-create-table-if-not-exists)

Comment: It doesn't seem like a duplicate to me.  They say that the feature was fixed in Postgres 9.1, but we're using redshift, which is branched off of a much earlier version of Postgres.  Also, the solution offered in the linked post relies on a UDF, which redshift does not support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I couldn't find anything in the redshift docs, and at this point I'm
> just guessing as to how to fix this. Is this something I just can't do
> in redshift?

Indeed this combination of `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` AND `IF NOT EXISTS` is not possible in Redshift (per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html)). Concerning PostgreSQL, it's possible since **version 9.5**.

On SO, this is discussed here: [PostgreSQL: Create table if not exists AS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896843/postgresql-create-table-if-not-exists-as) . The accepted answer provides options that don't require any UDF or procedural code, so they're likely to work with Redshift too.

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-table-as/