# INSERT INTO table if exists or else CREATE TABLE

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgscript

I have a pgscript that runs in a loop.

```
SET @id = 1;
BEGIN
WHILE @id <= 10

/*
CREATE TABLE tbl_name AS
SELECT * FROM main_tbl
WHERE id = @id
;

INSERT INTO tbl_name
SELECT * FROM main_tbl
WHERE id = @id
*/

SET @id = @id + 1;

END
```

For the first iteration `id=1`, I want my script to create a table because the table does not exist. For the upcoming loop `id=2...3...4...so on`, I want the script to insert into the table that was created.

Currently, I am creating an empty table before running the PgScript. Is there a way to write a script that creates the table for the first loop and insert in the upcoming iterations?

Comment: You should make it clear in your question that you are talking about a feature, `PgScript`, that is `pgAdmin` specific.

Comment: Why not create the table before the loop?

Comment: "*Currently, I am creating an empty table before running the PgScript*" - what's wrong with that? You also don't need pgScript or even a loop to do what you want. A simple `insert into target_table select * from some_table where id between 1 and 10` will be much more efficient. Plus it would work with any SQL client

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    word VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO words
        VALUES(DEFAULT, '1234');

SELECT *
FROM words;
```

Comment: [Possible link to help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896843/postgresql-create-table-if-not-exists-as)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Now this example will works