# Finding postgres executables on travis-ci

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci

I have tests that work locally when connecting to a Postgres server version 10.5 but which [fail on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/mikesamuel/attack-review-testbed/jobs/438755825), apparently due to a use of [`IF NOT EXISTS` syntax](https://github.com/mikesamuel/attack-review-testbed/blob/c87818475a261347e9bf4c4c23b4d5b7748b0508/lib/db-tables.js#L57-L65) that was apparently [added in Postgres 9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7438222/20394).

My `.travis.yml` is:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
   - "8"
   - "9"
   - "10"
   - "stable"

# Use faster Docker architecture on Travis.
sudo: false

services:
  - postgresql

script:        ./scripts/validate.sh
after_success: npm run coveralls
```

I tried several variants from "[Using a different postgresql version](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#using-a-different-postgresql-version)":

> The Travis CI build environments use version 9.2 by default on Trusty images, but other versions from the official PostgreSQL APT repository are also available. To use a version other than the default, specify only the major.minor version in your `.travis.yml`:

but then builds started failing on `which postgres` so it looks like there's no longer a `postgres` on `PATH`.

I tried manually appending to the path in `before_script` to add `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/` to PATH per [postgresql-10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/postgresql-10/filelist) but that didn't help.

I don't need to start a database service on a well-known port -- my test and local development scripts run `initdb` and start up a local database that the tests connect to via a named pipe.

How can I get a modern version of a postgres server binary and related tools like initdb available to my test scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I did a search for .travis.yml files that mention postgres on Github.

I found the magic incantation below which works for me, but I have no idea why.

I replaced

```
services:
  - postgresql
```

with

```
addons:
  postgresql: "9.6"
```

Previously I had used addons, but in addition to services instead of in place of.