# How to access the "notice" value from Postgresql when using `create table if not exists`

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, ddl, create-table

I have the statement `create table if not exists` so that my code does not try to create the table over and over. I would like to print a message of "Table already created" if the table already exists but I don't know how to access the "notice" spoken of in the documentation so I can use it in a conditional statement.

From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> `IF NOT EXISTS`
> Do not throw an error if a relation with the same name already exists. A notice is issued in this case. Note that there is no guarantee that the existing relation is anything like the one that would have been created.

Comment: It's not clear what do you want. When you're trying to re-create a table with `IF NOT EXISTS` the notice is actually being raised, and table is not being created. What else do you need?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using Python3. @ginkul, I would like to produce a message that prints to the console that the table already exists.

Answer (score 0):

To raise your own NOTICE / WARNING / EXCEPTION, take a different approach. Like:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables 
              WHERE  schemaname = 'myschema'
              AND    tablename  = 'mytable') THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Table myschema.mytable already created.';
   ELSE
      CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (i integer);  -- your table definition here
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL create table if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766046/postgresql-create-table-if-not-exists/7438222#7438222)