# Conditionally execute create command in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want to create a SQL function that can perform the following task - It should check whether a schema exists and if it doesn't, the function should create one.

Here is an example of such a function -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_schema_if_not_exists() RETURNS void AS $body$
DECLARE schema_count INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) into schema_count FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'my_schema';
  if schema_count = 0 THEN
    CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;
  END IF;
END;
$body$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Now there are two different kinds of users which this function can have - (1) Permitted to create schema, and (2) Not permitted to create schema. I want this function to error out only when a user, not permitted to creating schema, tries to create a schema when one does not exists.

The problem with this approach is that the user of kind (2) is not able to call function `create_schema_if_not_exists`.

How should I approach this problem now?

***Edit***

So here is what I want -

- If a user of kind (2) tries to create schema when one already exists then nothing should happen.
- If a user of kind (1) tries to create schema when one already exists then nothing should happen.
- If a user of kind (1) tries to create schema when one doesn't already exists then the schema should be created.
- If a user of kind (2) tries to create schema when one doesn't already exists then permission error should be thrown.

Comment: Why not simply use `create schema if not exists ...`? The privilege to create a schema should not be controlled in a function but by granting (or revoking) the `create` privilege on the database

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me: You now have to create a function when you actually want to create a schema. Why don't you just create the schema?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
In my use case, I can't enforce the postgres version. AFAIK `create schema if not exists` do not work well with postgres 9.1 or under.

Comment: All supported Postgres versions provide that option. You shouldn't use such an outdated version anyway.

Comment: For the other part of your comment @a_horse_with_no_name, I do have proper privileges set up for users of the database. I just want to write a function (or something similar) that should try to create only when schema does not exists.

Comment: Totally agree with you @a_horse_with_no_name . But this is something which I do not have control of. Users of my code can have any older versions of postgresql. This is why I am wary of using `create schema is not exists`!

Comment: Additionaly, `create schema if not exists` would error out when an under-privileged user tries to run it while database already has that schema. This is not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Postgres 9.3 or later](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createschema.html) simply use:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema;
```

Besides being simpler, it also avoids race conditions in the below workaround.

---

To make it work without raising an exception when the schema already exists, and for outdated versions of Postgres, too:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_schema_if_not_exists()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace WHERE nspname = 'my_schema') THEN
      CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL create table if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766046/postgresql-create-table-if-not-exists/7438222#7438222)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

You still get an exception for for missing privileges **if (and only if)** control actually reaches the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement, i.e. the schema does not exist already, as requested. Notably, that's also true for your original version. I just made it simpler and faster. Your statement in the question seems to be a misunderstanding:

> The problem with this approach is that the user of kind (2) is not able to call function `create_schema_if_not_exists`.

A missing `CREATE` privilege on the database would not prevent a role from calling either function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Erwin. Although, I still see the permission issue. Would you mind explaining why your solution should work?

Comment: @Rishabh: Actually, yours should, too. I added a bit above.

Comment: Ahhh... Is it so? It seems so. Certainly a misunderstanding on my part. Thanks for raising it Erwin!