# SQLexception when table exists

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, jdbc

I want to type a command with JDBC to create a table, but after first compilation, when table is already generated, every next one throws exception. I dont understand how is this possible, because I've put [IF NOT EXISTS] term there, so there should be no SQL error.

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            Connection conn = BazaDanych.Polacz();
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

           String command = "CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] testowatabela2 (id INTEGER, wartosc DOUBLE PRECISION);";

            stat.execute(command);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception in Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `catch(SQLException e)
        {` to `catch(SQLException e)
        { e.printStackTrace();` and copy/paste the output.

Comment: Some databases do not support the IF NOT EXISTS construction.

Comment: You get a SQLException if there is a problem with the SQL command you're tring to run - and it doesn't match the syntax of any version of SQL I know so that's possible!

Comment: Should the IF NOT EXISTS be in square brackets?

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error in or close to "["
  Position: 14
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags

Comment: Ewald it should as far as I know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, the brackets enclosing the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause come verbatim from the documentation:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html

but they must not be present in an actual `CREATE TABLE` statement, since the brackets mean that the clause is **optional**.

Another thing to consider is that `IF NOT EXISTS` is a new feature of PostgreSQL 9.1, so it would fail with older versions. If you're not sure of the version you're using, run in SQL: `select version()`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM sysobjects 
           WHERE xtype='u' AND name='testowatabela2')
    CREATE TABLE testowatabela2 (id INTEGER, wartosc DOUBLE PRECISION)
```

### Edit

Just leave the `[IF NOT EXISTS]` part. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435471/575376) it does not matter if the table exists or not.

Comment: @Noran: This syntax won't work in PostgreSQL so don't bother trying (juergen added it before your question was tagged with PostgreSQL)